# adding global objects to wpf application

Tags: wpf, xaml

in my App.xaml 
iv'e initialized an object which i wan't to use in different classes in my application

```
 <Application.Resources>
      <local:DalEngine x:Key="_engine" x:Name="_engine"/>        
 </Application.Resources>
```

how can i Reference this object in code from a class with in the same namespace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace does not matter, you can use `Application.Current.FindResource`. (Or directly `Application.Current.Resources["_engine"]`)

Comment: @eranotzer: You're welcome. Also note that on `FrameworkElements` you can call [`FindResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) directly as it will also check in the application if the key is not found locally.

Comment: i can't say i understand ..
could you give me an example ?

Comment: @eranotzer: Well, if you have some data class you do not have a `FindResource` method, if you however write code in your `MainWindow` for example you already have an instance method called `FindResource` which you can call. On your data-class you need to get the resource using `Application.Current.*`.